# install.packages() having issues with setwd()

Tags: r, package, installation

I'm attempting to install a package in R (v3.4 on Linux (64-bit)) and am being told that the execution was halted.

I attempted to log out of R and clear out my History and Environment.  Below is the cod and the output I am getting:

```
> install.packages('zip')
Installing package into ‘/home/clang/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4’ (as ‘lib’ is
unspecified) trying URL
'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/zip_1.0.0.tar.gz' Content type
'application/x-gzip' length 60823 bytes (59 KB)
================================================== downloaded 59 KB

Error: 1:7: unexpected '/' 1: setwd(/
          ^ Execution halted Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘zip’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpaFlNP9/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: I would not expect a call to `setwd` in any of the scripts (installation or otherwise) within the package `zip`. Do you have a call to `setwd` anywhere in your `~/.Rprofile` or similar files? It looks like some call has missed quoting the path.

Comment: Like @r2evans asked, where's your working directory? what `getwd()` returns?

Comment: Laksitha, I don't think that the actual directory matters much, it's that something is trying to change it (incorrectly).